# How to make a cone of a certain thickness

Tags: geometry

I would like to make a cone of thickness 1 with the equation
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}−\frac{(z−h)^2}{h^2}=0 \quad \text{where } 0\le z \le h.
$$
In order to define the inner wall, I would think to find the normal vector and subtract it from the surface at every point. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: It is more or less clear how to do it if $a=b$. What do you mean exactly by "thickness"?

Comment: Actually having a cone with thickness is not really meaningful because you will have an adaptative thickness relatively to the height. Otherwise it is an up-troncated cone.